# Как в RecyclerView по нажатию на картинку перейти в другую активити

Tags: android, recyclerview

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться. Формируем 2 различных `CardView` в `RecyclerView`. Необходимо, чтобы по нажатию на картинку `R.drawable.e010`, к примеру, переходил на новое активити с названием е010.

```
@override    
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_engine);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        MyCustomAdapter adapter = new MyCustomAdapter(initData());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    }
    public List<Message> initData() {
        Intent as1 = getIntent();
        int as = as1.getIntExtra("name", -1);
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Position = " + as, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



      if (as==1) {
        list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(new Message(R.string.like, R.drawable.e010));
        list.add(new Message(R.string.like, R.drawable.e012));
        list.add(new Message(R.string.like, R.drawable.e006));
        list.add(new Message(R.string.like, R.drawable.e005));

        return list;
    }else {
        list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(new Message(R.string.like, R.drawable.e001));
        list.add(new Message(R.string.like, R.drawable.e002));
        list.add(new Message(R.string.like, R.drawable.e036));
        list.add(new Message(R.string.like, R.drawable.e005));
        return list;

        }}
```

Comment: Нужен, как минимум, код адаптера

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем, я нашел [статью](http://venomvendor.blogspot.ru/2014/07/setting-onitemclicklistener-for-recycler-view.html) и переделал все под себя.

Answer (score 2):

Вам нужно получить ссылку на ImageView, которая находится в вашем CardView. Поставить на него листенер на клик и по клику открывать новую активити.

```
imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(this, е010.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
```